# AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions always returning (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to get a scheduled `UILocalNotification` with the app fully closed (terminated), since the method `didReceiveLocalNotification:` doesn't get called, I'm trying to use the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
NSLog(@"LOCAL NOTIFICATION - %@",localNotification);
if (localNotification) {
    //HANDLE THE NOTIFICATION
}
return YES;
```

}

That is the way I'm creating the `UILocalNotification` :

```
UILocalNotification * notificationRH = [UILocalNotification new];
notificationRH.fireDate = date;
notificationRH.repeatInterval = repetition;
notificationRH.alertBody = body;
notificationRH.alertAction = title;
notificationRH.hasAction = title ? 1 : 0;
notificationRH.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notificationRH.soundName = sounds ? UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName : nil;
notificationRH.userInfo = @{@"test": title};
```

But the problem is that the `launchOptions` on the method always return `(null)`, and I'm not able to get the Notification triggered while the app was closed. Does anyone can help me with this ??
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I don't see you actually _scheduling_ the local notification. It is not enough to _make_ it; you have to hand it _to the system_.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's because this is just the creation, a manager class schedule the notification, it's working, i just can't handle it if the app is on background or terminated. Otherwise i just use didReceiveLocalNotification, is working fine that way...

Comment: I'm suggesting, then, that the "manager class" is doing this wrong somehow. If it were doing it right, you'd be receiving the local notification in the app delegate.

Comment: Prove that the notification is being scheduled: show a screen shot of the alert that appears _when the app is not running_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have forgotten to schedule the local notification:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/scheduleLocalNotification:

Comment: I'm scheduling the localNotification, this is just the code that creates, another class schedule it, it's working, it shows for me on the screen, and, when the app is active it calls the method didReceiveLocalNotification, the problem happens when the app is on background or terminated.

Comment: If your local notification is being scheduled, then as long as your app is not in the foreground when it fires, you will get `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or both — not neither — when the user taps the alert's Launch button.

Comment: I get what you are saying, when i click the notification it is working, i was testing the wrong way (without touching the notification) thanks for the help. But i want to identify that the notification has been triggered, even if the user don't touch the notification, because i have a remembering badge inside the app that will be activated, do you know if there's a way to do that ? Thanks a lot !! XD

Comment: You can't do it. That's not what a local notification is. If you need to remember that you scheduled a notification, it is up to _you_ to remember it. You can then check its fire date against the current date.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Matt.. this conversation really helped me a lot... i'll do the verification using the fire Date... Thank you very much !!!!! XD